# python how to concatenate dynamic parts of html template together and then print them as one html

Tags: python

this is my `template.py`:

```py
first = '''<html><head></head>
<body>
<h1>This is header H1</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>'''
uid='{uid}'
second='''</td>
    <td>'''
name='{name}'
third='''</td>
    <td>'''
phone='{phone}'
fourth='''</td>
    <td>'''
email='{email}'
fifth='''</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>'''
```

I'm going to email this, but I think if I print as the expected output, it should work.

I have a list like this:

```py
list1 = [
    {'uid': 1, 'name': 'saeed1', 'phone': '+989100000000', 'email': 'sample1@gmail.com'},
    {'uid': 2, 'name': 'saeed2', 'phone': '+989200000000', 'email': 'sample2@gmail.com'},
    {'uid': 3, 'name': 'saeed3', 'phone': '+989300000000', 'email': 'sample3@gmail.com'},
    {'uid': 4, 'name': 'saeed4', 'phone': '+989400000000', 'email': 'sample4@gmail.com'},
]
```

Expected output is:

```html
<html><head></head>
<body>
<h1>This is header H1</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>saeed1</td>
    <td>+989100000000</td>
    <td>sample1@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>saeed2</td>
    <td>+989200000000</td>
    <td>sample2@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>saeed3</td>
    <td>+989300000000</td>
    <td>sample3@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>saeed4</td>
    <td>+989400000000</td>
    <td>sample4@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my attempt:

```py
import template
for n in list1:
    uid = template.uid.format(uid=n['uid'])
    name = template.name.format(name=n['name'])
    phone = template.phone.format(phone=n['phone'])
    email = template.email.format(email=n['email'])
    combined = template.first + uid + template.second + name + template.third + phone + template.fourth + email + template.fifth
    print(combined)
```

I know this is not correct, and I think objects like `template.first`, `template.second`, etc. which are static should be outside the `for` loop, but I have not idea what to do next and how to combine them.

Comment: You could have one variable with your formattable string. And call `.format(uid=, name=, ...)` in one single format call.

Comment: @Torxed thanks, but how to use them separately in output? They're not in one part of the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of posible solution, may this can help you

```
start_document = '''<html><head></head>
<body>
<h1>This is header H1</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    '''
added_content ='<tr><td>{uid}</td><td>{name}</td><td>{phone}</td><td>{email}</td></tr>'
end_document = '</table></body></html>'

list1 = [
    {'uid': 1, 'name': 'saeed1', 'phone': '+989100000000', 'email': 'sample1@gmail.com'},
    {'uid': 2, 'name': 'saeed2', 'phone': '+989200000000', 'email': 'sample2@gmail.com'},
    {'uid': 3, 'name': 'saeed3', 'phone': '+989300000000', 'email': 'sample3@gmail.com'},
    {'uid': 4, 'name': 'saeed4', 'phone': '+989400000000', 'email': 'sample4@gmail.com'},
]
filled_table = ''
for part_content in list1:
    filled_table_row = added_content.format(**part_content)
    filled_table += filled_table_row

total_document = start_document + filled_table + end_document
print(total_document)
```